# Why does gas turbine engine have pressure oil supply tube and the scavenge oil tube?

Tags: jet-engine, turbine

What is the function of pressure oil supply line tube and the scavenge oil tube on turbo shaft engine?

Comment: To lubricate [shaft bearings](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/35820/how-does-a-labyrinth-seal-work-when-the-engine-isnt-rotating)? Is this a homework?

Comment: Are you asking why the engine is lunricated?

Comment: One thing to note here is that with gas turbine engines the purpose of the oil is roughly 80% for cooling of the bearings and %20 for lubrication (also for the bearings). Unlike piston engines where almost 100% of the oil's purpose is for lubrication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oil Pressure lines typically sends oil to the Bearings and Gearboxes of the Engine, from the oil pump.

The Scavange lines typically collects the oil from those areas and send it back to the Oil tank, getting cooled and filtered along the way.