# Will N1 shaft turn at the same time as N2 shaft?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance, boeing-737, turbofan

For Turbo Fan Engine CFM56-7, was wondering how come the Fan blades (N1 shaft) turns when I turn the N2 Shaft manually.

I thought N1 shaft is connected to the fan and booster rotor and LPT rotor and N2 shaft is connected to the HPC and HPT rotor and both are on individual spools.

So if the N2 shaft turns, by right anything on the N1 shaft will not turn right?

Comment: If wind blows from the rear the fan sometimes rotates backwards, even with the turbine idling. I've seen this at least once at the airport.

Answer (score 6):

Both shafts are not connected directly. But there are still ways to transfer rotation from one to the other. The most obvious one would be the airflow generated by N2 turning the LPT. But also the bearings between both are not totally without friction and so will also transfer some rotation.

Comment: Yeah if he's turning the fan by hand it's going to be just bearing drag.

Comment: "*bearings between both are not totally without friction*", there is only one. On the other hand, N1 is also centered within frames [by three bearings](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/25879/3201). So there is possibly more friction tending to maintain N1 stationary than friction tending to rotate it.

Comment: @mins I don't think counting bearings is a good way to estimate friction.

Comment: @Sanchises: Sure this is not accurate engineering, but when bearings of the same diameter, and all with balls, are not lubricated, I believe they won't be very different. In addition #1 which is on the fan shaft (rotating with N1) is a large one, likely the one with the most friction when not lubricated. So you're right, but let see if a mechanics can confirm or deny.

Comment: I still don't understand. If you turn the Fan, the LPT will rotate, If you turn the N2 via the handcranking pad, HPC and HPT will rotate. N1 and N2 shaft are both individual shaft controlling different things. If N1 turns, N2 will not move right?

Comment: On a CFM56, there is an intershaft bearing between the N1 and N2 shafts (#4 bearing at the aft end).  So for this engine, yes, some slight friction in the bearings can transfer torque between the shafts. This is also true for some cousins of the CFM56 like CF34-10 and F110.  However, for the majority of jet engine designs, bearings connect from the rotor to the stator, not rotor to rotor.  So for most engines, bearing friction cannot transfer torque between shafts.