# What legacy turbojet would have detailed documentation and drawings available for free or cheap?

Tags: jet-engine, aircraft-manufacturer

I am fascinated by the technology of jet engines. As a hobby, I might like to create a detailed animated 3D model of one (and publish it with a Creative Commons license). Obviously I am not going to find any actual detailed technical drawings of recent or current in-production engines. They are trade secrets or even military secrets. But models from the 50s or early 60s might be a different story. Looking for suggestions for a model for which ample documentation is available, for free or for a reasonable price. It is not important as such whether it is a British, American, or French or other continental European design.

(I am at the moment building an add-on for Microsoft Flight Simulator of the English Electric Lightning that uses the Rolls-Royce Avon Mk 302, and have not been able to find any detailed information about that late Avon model. Some documentation for earlier Avon models yes, but not very detailed drawings. So the Avon is not the answer. Anyway, for that purpose I don't need to model the engine in great detail. It would just be nice to at least get the dimensions and number of compressor and turbine blades and stator vanes correct, if I bother modelling those.)

Perhaps even some Soviet one (with ideas "borrowed" from a Western model)? One might imagine that when the USSR collapsed, lots of military-related technical manuals and drawings ended up for sale to enthusiasts. I don't know Russian but drawings with measurements would be useful anyway.

Comment: For the level of details and accuracy you're seeking, it is possible to use publicly available documents and obtain something credible enough for animation, even for modern turbo-engines. You can start from a [general drawing](https://avia.superforum.fr/viewimage?u=https%3A%2F%2Fnsa39.casimages.com%2Fimg%2F2018%2F04%2F30%2F180430092759772322.jpg), and then look for parts at vendors, or [maintenance pictures](https://aerossurance.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/N30401-united-b739-cfm56-7-titanium-fire-hpc-rotor-damage.jpg). Be aware using Blender for CAD drawings is a nightmare, but feasible.

Comment: Many data can be retrieved from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KjYw0GdRpm0) (this is still the same engine)

Comment: @mins Aren't the LP compressor fan blades oriented the wrong way in that video? As in that video, they would push the air the wrong direction, no? Compare to the fan blades. The HP compressor blades are the right way.

Comment: You're right, the fan blades are correctly shown, the LPC blades are wrong, as well as the stator vanes! [Correct orientation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uc6Ds.png)  - [source](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/25877/3201). A [view of similar LPC blades](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fichier:CFM56_Low_Pressure_Compressor.JPG).